# Asp.Net Core Logging at Startup with Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a asp.net core application that is now deployed on Azure Web App using Team Foundation deployment.
At the moment, **for testing purposes** the application goes live with the following options:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   InitializeDatabase(app);

   loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
   loggerFactory.AddDebug();
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
...
}
```

And the log verbosity is configured as following:

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
```

But we have a serious problem.
If, **an error** occurs **during startup** inside the startup.cs class, nothing is traced and it becomes impossible for us to understand what is going on.

The developer page works fine as far as an exception is raised while the application is running, but if we get an exception during startup, no errors are raised except a common error page like this one:

[image]

Which honestly, is quite useless.
Even by enabling the Application Insights or the Application Log in Azure Web Application, I still don't get the real exception. Any way of achieving this?